# "SQL command not properly ended" (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm trying to insert 3 rows into 2 different tables by doing this:

```
INSERT INTO GAMES.ATHLETE (ATHLETE_NO, ATHLETE_NAME, ATHLETE_BIRTHDATE, ATHLETE_BIRTHPLACE, ATHLETE_BORN_COUNTRY, ATHLETE_GENDER, ATHLETE_HEIGHT, ATHLETE_WEIGHT, ATHLETE__TEAM_COUNTRY)
VALUES ('12345', 'Saif Haseeb', '08-NOV-1995', 'Clayton', 'AUS', 'M', '176', '75', 'AUS'), ('12323',  'Rajandeep', '01-FEB-1995', 'Melbourne', 'AUS', 'M', '180', '77', 'AUS'), ('2818', 'Jen Selter', '18- APR-1993', 'Paris', 'FRA', 'F', '169', '63', 'FRA')
INSERT INTO GAMES.COMPETES (ATHLETE_NO, DISCIPLINE_CODE, SG_GAMENO)
VALUES ('12345', 'FB', '30'), ('12323', 'FB', '30'), ('2818', 'TT', '29')
INSERT INTO GAMES.VENUE (VENUE_NO, VENUE_NAME, VENUE_LOCATION, VENUE_USEDFROM, VENUE_USEDTO,    VENUE_SEATINGCAPACITY, VENUE_STRUCTURE, VENUE_USE)
VALUES ('SY', 'SYDNEYSTADIUM', 'SYDNEY', '14-AUG-2014', '19-AUG-2014', '98172', 'A', 'Y');
```

However I keep getting the error in the title. Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: What is the error message ??

Comment: You are missing the `;` to terminate each statmeent.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I disagree with that. In the list of questions on the homepage I find it very useful to be able to distinguish the different DBMS but just looking at the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are three Statements, but you forgot to end each with a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't let you type `insert into ... values (...),(...)` like PostgreSQL does you need to split it into several inserts:

```
INSERT INTO GAMES.ATHLETE (ATHLETE_NO, ATHLETE_NAME, ATHLETE_BIRTHDATE, ATHLETE_BIRTHPLACE, ATHLETE_BORN_COUNTRY, ATHLETE_GENDER, ATHLETE_HEIGHT, ATHLETE_WEIGHT, ATHLETE__TEAM_COUNTRY)
VALUES ('12345', 'Saif Haseeb', '08-NOV-1995', 'Clayton', 'AUS', 'M', '176', '75', 'AUS');
INSERT INTO GAMES.ATHLETE (ATHLETE_NO, ATHLETE_NAME, ATHLETE_BIRTHDATE, ATHLETE_BIRTHPLACE, ATHLETE_BORN_COUNTRY, ATHLETE_GENDER, ATHLETE_HEIGHT, ATHLETE_WEIGHT, ATHLETE__TEAM_COUNTRY) 
VALUES ('12323',  'Rajandeep', '01-FEB-1995', 'Melbourne', 'AUS', 'M', '180', '77', 'AUS'); 
INSERT INTO GAMES.ATHLETE (ATHLETE_NO, ATHLETE_NAME, ATHLETE_BIRTHDATE, ATHLETE_BIRTHPLACE, ATHLETE_BORN_COUNTRY, ATHLETE_GENDER, ATHLETE_HEIGHT, ATHLETE_WEIGHT, ATHLETE__TEAM_COUNTRY) 
VALUES ('2818', 'Jen Selter', '18- APR-1993', 'Paris', 'FRA', 'F', '169', '63', 'FRA')
INSERT INTO GAMES.COMPETES (ATHLETE_NO, DISCIPLINE_CODE, SG_GAMENO)
VALUES ('12345', 'FB', '30');
INSERT INTO GAMES.COMPETES (ATHLETE_NO, DISCIPLINE_CODE, SG_GAMENO) 
VALUES ('12323', 'FB', '30'), ('2818', 'TT', '29');
INSERT INTO GAMES.VENUE (VENUE_NO, VENUE_NAME, VENUE_LOCATION, VENUE_USEDFROM, VENUE_USEDTO, VENUE_SEATINGCAPACITY, VENUE_STRUCTURE, VENUE_USE)
VALUES ('SY', 'SYDNEYSTADIUM', 'SYDNEY', '14-AUG-2014', '19-AUG-2014', '98172', 'A', 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Place Semicolon at the end of each statement.**

```
INSERT INTO GAMES.ATHLETE (ATHLETE_NO, ATHLETE_NAME, ATHLETE_BIRTHDATE, ATHLETE_BIRTHPLACE, ATHLETE_BORN_COUNTRY, ATHLETE_GENDER, ATHLETE_HEIGHT, ATHLETE_WEIGHT, ATHLETE__TEAM_COUNTRY)
VALUES ('12345', 'Saif Haseeb', '08-NOV-1995', 'Clayton', 'AUS', 'M', '176', '75', 'AUS'), ('12323',  'Rajandeep', '01-FEB-1995', 'Melbourne', 'AUS', 'M', '180', '77', 'AUS'), ('2818', 'Jen Selter', '18- APR-1993', 'Paris', 'FRA', 'F', '169', '63', 'FRA');


INSERT INTO GAMES.COMPETES (ATHLETE_NO, DISCIPLINE_CODE, SG_GAMENO)
VALUES ('12345', 'FB', '30'), ('12323', 'FB', '30'), ('2818', 'TT', '29');


INSERT INTO GAMES.VENUE (VENUE_NO, VENUE_NAME, VENUE_LOCATION, VENUE_USEDFROM, VENUE_USEDTO,    VENUE_SEATINGCAPACITY, VENUE_STRUCTURE, VENUE_USE)
VALUES ('SY', 'SYDNEYSTADIUM', 'SYDNEY', '14-AUG-2014', '19-AUG-2014', '98172', 'A', 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for inserting multiple rows in Oracle

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
  INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
  INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```